# if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

This probably looks like a duplicate, but nevertheless, i couldn't make it work.
What i'm trying to do is with every click, get a certain value, add it to already existing one in cookies, and replace the cookie value with a new total. And i still get not a number error

```
var nextqurl = $(".nav-next a").attr('href');
    var curcookie = $.cookie('test');
    var initscore = 0;
    alert(curcookie);
    $(".answer").click(function(){
        var score = $(this).attr('id');
        var updatedscore = parseInt(curcookie) + parseInt(score);
        if (typeof curcookie === 'undefined') {
            $.cookie('test',initscore, {path: '/'});
            }
        else
        {
            $.cookie('test',updatedscore, {path: '/'});
            }
        $.cookie('test',updatedscore, {path: '/'});
        window.location.replace(nextqurl);
        });
    });
```

p.s.
cookies are working fine

Comment: Posting the actual error may help.

Comment: check if `score` contains anything?

Comment: Have you tried `var curcookie = $.cookie('test') || 0;`. Im guessing the value from the cookie isn't initially zero

Comment: There are no errors in console, but alert returns NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
var curcookie = parseInt($.cookie('test')) || 0;
```

And take the `parseInt` off the `parseInt(curcookie)` inside the handler

Comment: just var curcookie = parseInt($.cookie('test')) || 0; worked fine. Could you please explan too? p.s. i can only accept answer in 26 minutes

Comment: The uninitialized value of your cookie (curcookie) is undefined when there is initially no cookie, so `parseInt(curcookie) + 1` is NaN.